# In DRF how can one properly display the related name field from one model inside another?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to display all `doctors` that work at a certain `clinic` but keep getting `clinic.Doctor.None`. I'm trying to get a list of the doctors ids or names in there

http://localhost:8000/api/clinic/ results

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "doctors": "clinic.Doctor.None", //how to show list of ids or names here?
        "name": "Clinic number 1",
    },
    ...
]
```

This how I implemented my models, serializers and viewsets:

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Doctor(models.Model):
    clinic = models.ManyToManyField(Clinic, related_name="doctors")
```

```
class ClinicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    doctors = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)    
    class Meta:
        model = Clinic
        fields = '__all__'

class DoctorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
class ClinicViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Clinic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClinicSerializer

class DoctorViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Doctor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DoctorSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1: use [**`StringRelatedField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)

```
class ClinicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    doctors = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Clinic
        fields = '__all__'
```

#### Solution 2: use [**`SerializerMethodField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
class ClinicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    doctors = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_doctors(self, clinic):
        return clinic.doctors.values_list("name", flat=True) # You can use any valid field name instead of `name` here

    class Meta:
        model = Clinic
        fields = '__all__'
```

I would choose `SerializerMethodField` over `StringRelatedField` since it gives us more control over the data we wish to return from the field.

Comment: ```clinic.doctors.values_list("name", flat=True)``` how can I return both "name" and "last_name" here?

Comment: `values_list("field_1", "field_2", flat=True)`

Comment: one last question, ```values_list("field_1", "field_2")``` returns an array of arrays. How could I change this to a list of objects?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: could I then only get an array of ids (each doctor's id)?

Comment: You can iterate over `clinic.doctors.all()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221829/discussion-between-cuomo-and-arakkal-abu).